# Sending a variable to another viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios

I have two viewcontrollers. One contains a tableview. In the didselectrowforindexpath method i wanna send an object to another viewcontroller but the object is null when it is passed to the destination view controller.

The object that im sending is service_ID that belongs to the TableServiceNews class. The destination viewcontroller inherits TableServiceNews.

**Here is the code for didselectrow :-**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    TableServiceNews *serviceTable = [[TableServiceNews alloc]init];
    serviceTable.service_ID = [ServiceID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    serviceTable = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationServiceNews"];
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight
        animations:nil onComplete:^{
        CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController = serviceTable;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
        [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
    }];
}
```

The slidingviewcontroller method is using a class that i got from github, https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController is the link.

Comment: Try to print this value NSLog(@"val is %@",[ServiceID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

Comment: I did. It returns the value just fine but when i NSLog it in the destination views, its null.

Comment: Do one thing take a variable in Appdelegate and set it on didselectRowAtIndex and access the same variable from appdelegate in serviceTable viewdidload method

Comment: @ernaidu How can i access a variable that is defined in appdelegate in another viewcontroller?

Comment: declare @property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *ar; in .h and .m synthesize it.Then you can access it like Appdelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedapplicatin] delegate];NSString *var = del.propertyVariable;

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that service_ID is defined in the implementation (@synthesize) , if it didn't work, make sure to assign the value to it after you push the new viewcontroller to load it first.
I hope that was helpful

Comment: when i assign the value after the viewcontroller push the app crashes and i get this error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setService_ID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: I think you are pushing the wrong controller, '-[UINavigationController setService_ID:] means that the serviceID belongs to a navigation controller not a viewcontroller, review ur code

Comment: it worked! i changed the identifier and it worked. But the problem is that the viewcontroller is bundled with a navigationcontroller and i need it to show a navigationbar on top of the view. It works just fine when i change the identifier to the viewcontroller but it doesn show the navigationbar.

Comment: No not great! the navigationbar on top of the viewcontroller is gone now!

Comment: Rashid, you have to reorganize your application correctly, you don't have to remove the navigationbar, just call the function from the viewcontroller not the navigationbar

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
TableServiceNews *serviceTable = [[TableServiceNews alloc]init];
serviceTable.service_ID = [ServiceID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
serviceTable = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationServiceNews"];
```

with :

```
UIViewController *serviceTable = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationServiceNews"];
((TableServiceNews*)serviceTable).service_ID = [ServiceID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The problem might be assigning service_ID value before instantiating your serviceTable from storyboard.

By the way, instantiatViewControllerWithIdentifier return a UIViewController. So you need to cast it to use it like the subclass you've created.

Comment: I got this error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setService_ID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Ok thanks. Im going to try it but one more thing. Where should i alloc and init service_ID?

Comment: `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` instantiates and returns the view controller with the specified identifier.